# How can I check for a value in a conditional array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this piece of code that I would like to use

```
const traits = [{title:"hello", effect:"world"},{title:"foo", effect:"bar"}];
const [ traitsArray, settraitsArray ] = useState([]);
```

to be rendered as Checkbox element

```
{traits.map((items)=>{
   return <FormControlLabel
           label={items.title}
           key={items.title}
           control={<Checkbox data-value={items.title} checked={false} onChange={ e => {
              if(traitsArray.includes(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'))){
                 settraitsArray(prevState => prevState.filter(items => items !== e.target.getAttribute('data-value')))
              }
              else{
                 settraitsArray(prevState => prevState.concat(items))
              }
} }/>}/>})}
```

On checked item, I would like to check if any of the similar value exist in `traitsArray`, if *true*, delete the element from the array, and if *false*, add the element to the array.

But every single time I checked the item, it just keep on concatenating the array. Did I miss something, or did I code it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onChange` function you are checking to see if your array includes a string but then if it doesn't you're adding an object. Your function should look like this:

```js
(e) => {
  if(traitsArray.some(({title}) => title === items.title)){
   settraitsArray(prevState => prevState.filter(item => item.title !== items.title))
  } else {
    settraitsArray(prevState => prevState.concat(items))
  }

}
```

Comment: This one is very clean! One thing to add, what is the difference between `.some` and `.includes`? Both seems to works just as same to me.

Comment: `.includes` does a comparison between each item in the array and your parameter. This works well if your array is full of strings. However, if you are iterating over an array of objects, `.some` allows you to drill down in to the values you actually care about.

Answer (score 0):

Your "data-value" attribute is a string and "traitsArray" is an array of objects. Here .includes() function will always be false for matching a string to an object.

Answer (score 0):

In the else part, you are adding an object in your array

```
settraitsArray(prevState => prevState.concat(items))
```

While, when you are checking in the `if` condition, you are comparing against the `string` value of `e.target.getAttribute('data-value')`, which is `false`.

Just update the else condition like below to add the `data-value` in the `traitsArray` state.

```
settraitsArray(prevState => prevState.concat(e.target.getAttribute('data-value')))
```